# I'm having trouble with Google homepage, search results, Google Images. They are being showed in a very unusual way. What's the reason behind this?

Tags: google-chrome, html

All the things mentioned above are working fine in Firefox but I'm having problem in Google Chrome. I'm posting below the screenshots of both the browsers displaying the same pages differently.

1. Firefox :

   As I said, everything is normal in Firefox.

   [image]
2. Google Chrome :

   All the images are being displayed in a weird way. When I click on an image it redirects me to the page hosting the image, instead of zooming it. Also this error is displaying in the console.

   [image]

All other sites are working just fine on Chrome. Google homepage, images and search results are the places I've encountered problems on.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what to ask here. That said, it seems Google and Chrome has some issues with cross-domain frames

Comment: I see you have lots of add-ons in Chrome. Have you tried disabling them to see whether it's caused by an add-on?

Comment: Yes,I have tried disabling the extensions, but there's no change.

Comment: Reinstall chrome or don't use it....